# What happens to my committed files if I git pull?

Tags: php, git

Okay, I am already saying sorry if this is a repeated question.

Scenario:
I have my develop and master branch, I always work on develop branch. I made some changes and committed those changes. After that I planned to push the changes up to main repository, but it says I need to pull first.

Now, I know that there will be changes in the existing files. But my issue is what about the files that I committed?

What will happen to those committed files.

Looking forward to sort out this confusion. Thanks for helping. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you pull data from repository there might be some merge conflicts. 
If git will not be able to automatically merge your branch with repository branch git will throw merge conflict.
You will have to fix conflicts (chose which version of file you want).

Your changes will not be lost.

After you fix conflicts you will be able to push.

When not sure you can always make backup branch, so you have place to come back.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help. Got this sorted. It merged my changes and then proposed to resolve the conflicts. Cheers. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you check the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull), `git pull` will first fetch, and then merge the remote changes (this is the default behavior, you may configure git to do a rebase instead of merge).

So what will happen is git will merge your commits with the ones from the remote. You might have conflicts to solve, but you won't loose your work.

Comment: Thanks, I was only able to mark any one answer correct. Thanks for quick response. it helped and I resolved my issue. Cheers. :)

Comment: "you may configure git to do a rebase instead of merge": this was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!